# Impossible to connect to Database hosted by 1and1 from personal PC?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, database-connection

I have written a little winforms program in C# (MS Visual Studio Express 2010) for a friend to help manipulate her database hosted by 1and1.com. In her cpanel, on her MySQL Administration page, it says "Your MySQL databases are stored behind a firewall to protect your data. You can only access each one exclusively through your server. Direct access to your MySQL databases using a home PC (external ODBC connection) cannot be established."

I'm pretty new to MySQL and messing with server settings. Sorry if I don't use the right terms. I had some help changing the settings to allow for remote access, allowing all ip addresses, and I think even (temporarily) disabling the firewall. Being so new to all this, here's my question:

Despite the changes I've made, is it still going to be impossible to access these databases through my C# program? I've made a similar program and successfully run it with other hosting services (BlueHost, to be specific) Are there any settings I could change or any workarounds to make accessing her databases possible with 1and1?

Comment: So you changed the setting in cpanel, does it work? I'm guessing no. Can you ssh to the server? If so you may get it working with port forwarding, but I'm thinking 1and1 does not allow ssh.

Comment: "Direct access to your MySQL databases using a home PC (external ODBC connection) cannot be established." ... this pretty much says it all. Normally hosting companies allow a white list of IP addresses which lets them get through their firewall. Maybe check directly with 1and1 themselves.

Comment: @Elliott I can access with SSH--that's how we were able to change the other settings...port forwarding?

Comment: @Elliott, thank you. I will look into port forwarding. I'll report back here if I find anything definitive.